# MSWord List of Figures shows file path on mouse over

Tags: microsoft-word

In MSWord, when I generate a List Of Figures to point to an image with a caption, on Mouseover, it shows the actual file path. How do I remove it? I have searched everywhere before posting and did not find a solution.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file path you see is a "hyperlink" to the image on your machine that it will use to render the image.

If you want the "hyperlink" / file path to be removed / non-existent you can always copy your image into MSPAINT and then paste it into your word document. Then you will not have a file path or "hyperlink" appear.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the source image with the link and under Format Picture -> Alt Text you can remove the file path which is automatically added to there.